# Checksum or validate .tar file contents with directory in shell

Tags: shell-script, backup, tar, checksum, verification

Scenario:
Using Linux shell to back up a directory of many sub files and compressing the data with ‘tar -cvpJf filename.tar /savedir/’.

Goal:
Using shell — checksum or validate the newly created ‘.tar’ against the original directory.

Limitations:
Solution cannot involve downloading 3rd party support libraries. User cannot be part of the process.

Comments:
Basically, I am wondering if there is a tar flag I am missing that will validate upon creation of the tar, or maybe I can pipe the tar into some process?

Comment: I don't understand this question. The checksum of the `tar` archive will be different from whatever you used to create it.

Comment: You could extract the tar file into a temp directory (mkdir /foo && cd /foo && tar -xvf .../filename.tar) and then diff -r the two directories (diff -r /savedir /foo).   Or, would re-creating the tar archive  produce an identical file? (tar -cvpJf - /savedir/ | diff filename.tar -)

Comment: This will involve a little more effort than you seem to think it will. It can be done; see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091335/create-checksum-sha256-of-all-files-and-directories), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657173/storing-sha1-checksum-in-an-array-for-all-files-in-a-folder), and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/458326/sha1sum-for-a-directory-of-directories) for example. It's not a `tar` option IOW.

Comment: "*I am wondering if there is a tar flag I am missing*": Try `-W` or `--verify` (I don't know if this option is only available in GNU tar or POSIX tar, but since you use Linux, it should work).

Comment: @berndbausch The features of `gtar` to compare TAR archives against the filesystem are very limited. I recommend the older and more mature `star` that supports a `-diff` option that allows to compare the content and any meta data and even more: `star` allows to control which meta data is to be compared by specifying a list with the option `diffopts=`